# Codeigniter db_where in 3 joined tables

Tags: codeigniter, filter

So this code is a combination of 3 table joined, now i want to filter the query where only the request that a user can have is his/her own request and not from other user.. the problem is in where clause i have duplicated.

```
$this->db->order_by('loanrequest.ApplicationNo', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('loanrequest','loanapplication','user');
        $this->db->join('loanapplication','loanrequest.ApplicationNo = loanapplication.ApplicationNo');
        $this->db->join('user', 'user.userId = loanapplication.userId');    
        $this->db->where('loanapplication.userId', $this->session->userdata('userId'));
        $this->db->where('loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo');
        return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Is the second where even necessary?  You're already joining  `loanapplication` on the same condition.

Comment: if i left out first where only it doesnt even filter.. example user1 has only 2 request but instead it output the whole requests. that is what happen.

Comment: `where('loanapplication.userId', $this->session->userdata('userId'))` is necessary, but I think you can remove `where('loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not get what you have done in your join query but Here is how I do join in my CodeIgniter model.

You don't need to put this in where condition:

`$this->db->where('loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo');`

Because you have already done that in the join query.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('loanapplication')
            ->join('loanrequest', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo  = loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'left')
            ->join('user', 'user.userId  = loanapplication.userId', 'left')     
            ->where_in('loanapplication.userId',$this->session->userdata('userId'))
            ->order_by('loanrequest.ApplicationNo', 'DESC')                 
            ->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

I will recommend you should use `$this->db->last_query()` because it gives you a better idea about your query.

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) i got this error on ->get(); syntax

Comment: Plese I just forgot to remove the `;` from order_by. I have updated that. please try that code. @HanthonyTagam

Comment: Please let me inform about latest status of your problem @HanthonyTagam

Comment: your code is perfect...what are the other way to commend here?

Comment: sorry, @HanthonyTagam  I don't get what you are saying. `what are the other way to commend here? `  are you asking about `comment`.

Comment: im new here in stackoverflow usually if someone give the right answer i can accept the answer and vote up for useful answers right? is there other thing like subscribe or chat personally?

Comment: Yes SO has the chat system but for it requires some reputation point to do. And Also same with the vote up.  Plase Vist this links. [for-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)  & for [vote-up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)  and for comment on other question you need 50 reputation point.  @HanthonyTagam

Comment: if you have more question regarding SO then you can visit [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('loanapplication')
            ->join('loanrequest', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo  = loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'left')
            ->join('user', 'user.userId  = loanapplication.userId', 'left')     
            ->where_in('loanapplication.userId',$this->session->userdata('userId'))
            ->order_by('loanrequest.ApplicationNo', 'DESC');                    
            $result = $query->get();

           echo $this->db->last_query();exit; //use this to print your query so that you can get the actual issue 
           if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $result->result_array();
          } else
            return '';
```